# How to convert a big set of SQL queries into a single stored procedure that uses a variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to convert a big list of SQL statements into a PostgreSQL stored procedure that uses a variable, one that should be populated from the result of one SELECT.

If you want to see what has to be run, you can check it [here](https://gist.github.com/2352960)

As far as I know PostgreSQL does not allow use to use variables inside stored procedures that are using `SQL` language, so I'm looking for solutions that would require a minimal number of changes.

Comment: If you store `user_id` instead of `user_name`, then you only need to update the user name once; in the user table.  That's a core principle of relational databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier after you find the right syntax:

Here is the procedure `definition` for `plpgsql` language:

```
DECLARE myvar integer;
BEGIN
SELECT INTO myvar FROM ...;
-- use myvar
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be pretty repetitive. Will `EXECUTE` be of any help? [(manual about execute)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-execute.html) [(example and more information)](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql/vol2/ExecutingDynamicCommands.html) It allows you to run predefined queries and create new ones on the fly.